# R Shiny dataTableOutput all if not brushed

Tags: shiny

I have a renderDataTable object in my R Shiny App in the server application, that shows all titles of those games that are being brushed in a Scatterplot from the user and shows them in a datatable with some more statistics.

```
  output$dtable <- renderDataTable({ 
    brushedPoints(daten(), input$brush_plot) %>% na.omit()
    %>% select(GAME.NAME,input$x, input$y)
    })
  }
```

Now, I want to show all games by default, if the user does not brush the plot.
I think I have to use an if-else branch at the beginning of the renderDataTable function, but I dont know which arguments to pass..
I already tried `if (!input$brush_plot)` and `if(!brushedPoints())` .. and then `(daten()%>% select..)` but that didn't work..
How can I do that?

Comment: I think you want to check: ```if (length(input$brush_plot) > 0)```

Comment: yes thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :) if (length(input$brush_plot)==0) {
    daten()
  }
    else {brushedPoints(daten(), input$brush_plot) %>% na.omit() %>% select(GAME.NAME,input$x, input$y)}
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check:

```
if (length(input$brush_plot) > 0) {
    daten()
} else {
    brushedPoints(daten(), input$brush_plot) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    select(GAME.NAME,input$x, input$y)
}
```